# Generic list create by reflection and Implicit casting

Tags: c#, .net

I'm targeting version 4.0 of the .Net framework. I wrote the following simple code:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator A(B b)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

Then I created a generic list:

```
 var mylist = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(A)).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[]{});
```

When I want add a new instance of `B` the following code works:

```
((IList<A>)mylist).Add(new B());
```

However if I run the below code the following exception is thrown:

```
The value "B" is not of type "A" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
```

Parameter name: value

```
((IList)mylist).Add(new B());
```

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit conversion happens only in the first `Add` as you are adding an object of type `B` to a `IList<A>`. In the second case, you are adding it to the non-generic `IList`, which is a collection of objects and the implicit conversion doesn't take place and bombs when the object is actually added to your `List<A>`

Even this fails:

```
var mylist = new List<A>();
((IList<A>)mylist).Add(new B());
((IList)mylist).Add(new B())
```

You can do this, however:

```
((IList)mylist).Add((A)new B());
```

Comment: Thanks.But I write this code for test. In real code I get all type by reflection and I can't write  Add((A)new B());

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you cast your list to `IList<A>` and call `Add`, the compiler (implicitly) adds a cast to your `B` instance to `A`. In the second case, `IList` accepts only an `object` in the `Add` method. `B` is an object, so it's not cast to `A`. Therefore, when the method tries to add it internally to the underlying data structure, it raises the exception.

You can even test it through this code:

```
var fails = (A) (object) new B();
```

Since you ask how to solve the problem (although I don't see the necessity of casting your type to `IList` in this case), you can just explicitly cast your `B` to `A` when adding it. Example:

```
mylist.Add((A) new B());
```

Comment: Thanks.But I write this code for test. In real code I get all type by reflection and I can't write Add((A)new B());